# how to validate composite controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, servercontrols

Alright, this is a little bit complicated.

I have a composite control that contains textbox, required field validator and a button.
It is exposing a property called ValidationGroup.

It applies the ValidationGroup property to textbox , required field validator and the button.

Everything works fine.

The problem begins when I take out the button and place it out in the form with the same validation group.

Ideally it should have worked. But it doesn't.
Some say that composite controls have their own naming container and so this will not work.

If that is true, I don't understand why ? I mean they have the same validation group!

anyways, does anyone know how to fix this ?

here's my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using FCC.Web.UI.CustomControl;
using System.Xml;

namespace FCC.Web.UI.CustomControl
{
    [AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]
    [AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]
    [DefaultProperty("Value")]
    [ValidationProperty("Value")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:ValidationTextBox runat=server></{0}:ValidationTextBox>")]
    public class ValidationTextBox : CompositeControl, IDynamicControl
    {

        #region-- privatess --
        private TextBox textBox1;
        private RequiredFieldValidator requiredFieldValidator1;
        private RegularExpressionValidator regularExpressionValidator1, maxlengthValidator,integerValidator,decimalValidator;
        private string validationClasses, validationGroup, validationExpression, xmlElementName;
        private bool isRequired;
        private int maxlength;
        #endregion

        #region-- properties -- The following properties are deleted to child controls

        #region-- textbox --

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        [Description("Text displayed on the textbox")]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return textBox1.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                textBox1.Text = value;
            }
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Styles")]
        [Themeable(true)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public Style TextBoxStyle
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return textBox1.ControlStyle;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                //textBox1.Attributes["style"] = value;
                textBox1.ControlStyle.MergeWith(value);
            }
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Styles")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public string TextBoxCssClass
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return textBox1.CssClass;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                textBox1.CssClass = value;
            }
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public TextBoxMode TextMode
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return textBox1.TextMode;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                textBox1.TextMode = value;
            }
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Default")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public int MaxLength
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return maxlength;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();

                if (value > 0)
                {
                    maxlength = value;

                    textBox1.MaxLength = value;

                    maxlengthValidator.Enabled = true;

                    //maxlengthValidator.ValidationExpression = "^[a-zA-Z.]{0," + value + "}$";
                    maxlengthValidator.ValidationExpression = @"^[\s\S]{0," + value + "}$";
                    maxlengthValidator.ErrorMessage = "Maximum allowed charaters: " + value;
                }
            }
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Default")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public bool IsInteger
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return integerValidator.Enabled;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();

                if (value == true) // Is Integer
                {
                    integerValidator.Enabled = true;
                    regularExpressionValidator1.Enabled = false;
                    maxlengthValidator.Enabled = false;
                    decimalValidator.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    integerValidator.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Default")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        [Description("Error message that appears when textbox contain invalid integer")]
        public string InvalidIntegerErrorMessage
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return integerValidator.ErrorMessage.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "Invalid Number" : integerValidator.ErrorMessage;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                integerValidator.ErrorMessage = value;
            }
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Default")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public bool IsDecimal
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return decimalValidator.Enabled;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                if (value == true)
                {
                    decimalValidator.Enabled = true;
                    integerValidator.Enabled = false;
                    regularExpressionValidator1.Enabled = false;
                    maxlengthValidator.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    decimalValidator.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }


        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Default")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        [Description("Error message that appears when textbox contain invalid decimal number")]
        public string InvalidDecimalErrorMessage
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return decimalValidator.ErrorMessage.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "Invalid Number" : decimalValidator.ErrorMessage;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                decimalValidator.ErrorMessage = value;
            }
        }


        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Default")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        [Description("Name of XmlElement")]
        public string XmlElementName
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return xmlElementName;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                xmlElementName = value;
            }
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Default")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public string XmlElements
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>",XmlElementName,textBox1.Text);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region--required validation --

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        [Description("Error message that appears when text box is empty")]
        public String RequiredErrorMessage
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return requiredFieldValidator1.ErrorMessage.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "Required Field" : requiredFieldValidator1.ErrorMessage;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                requiredFieldValidator1.ErrorMessage = value;
            }
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Default")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        [Description("bool, representing text in the textbox is required field or not")]
        public bool IsRequired
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return isRequired;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                isRequired = value;
                requiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region-- regular expression validation --

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        [Description("Error message that appears when textbox contain invalid format string")]
        public String RegularExpressionErrorMessage
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return regularExpressionValidator1.ErrorMessage.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "Invalid Text" : regularExpressionValidator1.ErrorMessage;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                regularExpressionValidator1.ErrorMessage = value;
            }
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Default")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        [Description("Regular expression. Leave blank if you dont want to implement.")]
        public string RegularExpression
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return validationExpression;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();

                validationExpression = value;
                regularExpressionValidator1.ValidationExpression = value;
                regularExpressionValidator1.Enabled = true;

                integerValidator.Enabled = false;
                decimalValidator.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region--common--
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Default")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        [Description("cssClasses that apply to all validators")]
        public string ValidationErrorCssClass
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return validationClasses;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                validationClasses = value;

                requiredFieldValidator1.CssClass = value;
                regularExpressionValidator1.CssClass = value;
                maxlengthValidator.CssClass = value;
            }
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Default")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        [Description("Validation group for the textbox and inbuilt validations")]
        public string ValidationGroup
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                return validationGroup;

            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                validationGroup = value;

                requiredFieldValidator1.ValidationGroup = value;
                regularExpressionValidator1.ValidationGroup = value;
                maxlengthValidator.ValidationGroup = value;
                textBox1.ValidationGroup = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #endregion

        #region -- blank properties--
        public string EmptyText { get; set; }
        public string CommaSeparatedData { set; get; }
        public bool ShowDefaultItem { get; set; }
        public string DropDownCssClass { get; set; }
        #endregion

        protected override void RecreateChildControls()
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            Controls.Clear();

            #region--textbox--
            textBox1 = new TextBox();
            textBox1.ID = "textbox1";
            //textBox1.CssClass = TextBoxClass;
            textBox1.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.VerticalAlign] = "middle";

            //if (!validationGroup.IsNullOrEmpty())
            //{
            //    textBox1.ValidationGroup = validationGroup;
            //}
            #endregion

            #region--required field validator--
            requiredFieldValidator1 = new RequiredFieldValidator();
            requiredFieldValidator1.ID = "validator1";
            requiredFieldValidator1.ErrorMessage = RequiredErrorMessage;
            requiredFieldValidator1.CssClass = validationClasses;
            requiredFieldValidator1.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
            requiredFieldValidator1.ControlToValidate = textBox1.ID;
            requiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = false;
            requiredFieldValidator1.SetFocusOnError = true;
            //if (isRequired)
            //{
            //    requiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = true;
            //}

            //if (!validationGroup.IsNullOrEmpty())
            //{
            //    requiredFieldValidator1.ValidationGroup = validationGroup;
            //}

            #endregion

            #region-- regular expression validator--
            regularExpressionValidator1 = new RegularExpressionValidator();
            regularExpressionValidator1.ID = "validator2";
            regularExpressionValidator1.Enabled = false;
            regularExpressionValidator1.ErrorMessage = RegularExpressionErrorMessage;
            regularExpressionValidator1.CssClass = validationClasses;
            regularExpressionValidator1.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
            regularExpressionValidator1.ControlToValidate = textBox1.ID;
            regularExpressionValidator1.SetFocusOnError = true;
            //if (!validationGroup.IsNullOrEmpty())
            //{
            //    regularExpressionValidator1.ValidationGroup = validationGroup;
            //}
            #endregion

            #region -- maxlength validation --
            maxlengthValidator = new RegularExpressionValidator();
            maxlengthValidator.ControlToValidate = textBox1.ID;
            maxlengthValidator.ID = "validator3";
            maxlengthValidator.Enabled = false;
            maxlengthValidator.CssClass = validationClasses;
            maxlengthValidator.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
            maxlengthValidator.SetFocusOnError = true;

            //if (!validationGroup.IsNullOrEmpty())
            //{
            //    maxlengthValidator.ValidationGroup = validationGroup;
            //}

            #endregion

            #region--integer Validation--
            integerValidator = new RegularExpressionValidator();
            integerValidator.ID = "integervalidator";
            integerValidator.Enabled = false;
            integerValidator.ErrorMessage = InvalidIntegerErrorMessage;
            integerValidator.CssClass = validationClasses;
            integerValidator.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
            integerValidator.ControlToValidate = textBox1.ID;
            integerValidator.SetFocusOnError = true;
            integerValidator.ValidationExpression=@"^\d+$";
            #endregion

            #region -- decimal validation--
            decimalValidator = new RegularExpressionValidator();
            decimalValidator.ID = "decimalvalidator";
            decimalValidator.Enabled = false;
            decimalValidator.ErrorMessage = InvalidDecimalErrorMessage;
            decimalValidator.CssClass = validationClasses;
            decimalValidator.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
            decimalValidator.ControlToValidate = textBox1.ID;
            decimalValidator.SetFocusOnError = true;
            decimalValidator.ValidationExpression = @"(^\d*\.?\d*[1-9]+\d*$)|(^[1-9]+\d*\.\d*$)";

            #endregion

            this.Controls.Add(textBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(requiredFieldValidator1);
            this.Controls.Add(regularExpressionValidator1);
            this.Controls.Add(maxlengthValidator);
            this.Controls.Add(integerValidator);
            this.Controls.Add(decimalValidator);
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            AddAttributesToRender(writer);

            textBox1.RenderControl(writer);
            requiredFieldValidator1.RenderControl(writer);
            regularExpressionValidator1.RenderControl(writer);
            maxlengthValidator.RenderControl(writer);
            integerValidator.RenderControl(writer);
            decimalValidator.RenderControl(writer);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: > "Ideally it should have worked. But it doesn't." What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce the problem. Composite controls *do* implement `INamingContainer`, but that doesn't affect validation groups. Could you provide a small code example to help us troubleshoot?

Here's the code that worked for me:

**Composite control**

```
public class RequiredTextBox : CompositeControl
{
    private TextBox _textBox = new TextBox { ID = "T" };
    private RequiredFieldValidator _validator =
        new RequiredFieldValidator { ID = "V", ControlToValidate = "T", ErrorMessage = "*" };

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _textBox.Text; }
        set { _textBox.Text = value; }
    }

    public string ValidationGroup
    {
        get { return _validator.ValidationGroup; }
        set { _validator.ValidationGroup = value; }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(_textBox);
        this.Controls.Add(_validator);
    }
}
```

**ASPX**

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="ValidationSummary" /> 
    <ctl:RequiredTextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox" ValidationGroup="VG" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="VG" />
</form>
```

Comment: I re did the code according to shown by you. and it finally work. May be I was doing something wrong.

Comment: can you help me with one more thing?
I see that you have given and ID "TextBox" to your custom control on the form.

When I do that the client scripts of the control wont work but server side validation works.

When I dont give an ID to the control (on the form), Both client and server validation will work.

I can post my code if you want.

Comment: Yes, please provide your code. I tested both client-side and server-side validation with my code, and it seemed to work.

Comment: There's a bug: delete the call to `AddAttributesToRender` in your `Render` method. (This is causing the `<input>` element to get *two* `id` attributes, which is invalid HTML.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the answer of WHY this is happening, but you can do the things up by adding a public method to the Control that returns it's validation as a bool and then in the page add a `CustomValidator` and put something like:

```
args.IsValid = yourControl.publicMethod()
```

in it, I can't test it now but I bet it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, The idea is to have validators only inside composite control.. that why I am building composite control!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[ValidationProperty("Text")]
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:Class1 runat=server></{0}:Class1>")]
public class Class1: CompositeControl
{
    private TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
    private RequiredFieldValidator rfv = new RequiredFieldValidator();

    public string Text
    {
        //this will trigger validator inside
        get
        {
            this.rfv.Validate();
            return this.txtbox.Text; //you may need too loop each textbox to check if it's empty and return empty string, if so.
        }
    }
```

Now the button triggers validator inside composite control. I tried this and succeeded.